# Two bodies, one with mass m and the other with very very huge mass (tending to infinity), moving with velocity v and -v (opposite directions) collide

Tags: kinematics, momentum, collision

Assumption: The bodies are moving on the same axis, along their center of mass, and the bodies are perfectly spherical. There is no loss of kinetic energy after collision.

m2 >>> m1
v2 = -v1

Will the bodies stick together and move with the velocity v2, or will the lighter body move with a velocity v >>> v2?

Comment: I have updated my answer as a result of you comment about kinetic energy conservation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no loss of energy after collision.

In general terms this is a correct statement.

> Will the bodies stick together and move with the velocity v2, or will the lighter body move with a velocity v >>> v2?

It all depends on how you interpret the first statement.
If that statement read "There is no loss of **kinetic** energy after collision" then the two masses would not stick together but with the statement as given meaning all types of energy the question cannot be answered unless there was further information provided or an assumption was made eg after the collision the masses stuck together.

**Update**
Let the more massive body have a mass $M$ and the other body have a mass $m$.

If there are no external forces on the system comprising the two masses linear momentum must be conserved.
With $v\,\hat i$ and $-v \,\hat i$ as the initial velocities of the the more massive mass and the other mass before  the collision and $A\,\hat i$ and $a\hat \, i$ as their speeds velocity after the collision applying momentum conservation gives.

$$Mv\,\hat i -mv\,\hat i = MA\,\hat i + ma\,\hat i \Rightarrow Mv -mv = MA + ma$$

There is one equation and two unknowns $A$ and $a$.
The problem is soluble if the two masses stick together so that $A = a$ and the velocity after collision is $\left (\dfrac{M-m}{M+m} \right )v\,\hat i$

Now suppose that the collision is perfectly elastic which means that kinetic energy is conserved.
This produces the second equation which will enable the problem to be solved.
On doing the sums the more massive object has a velocity  $\dfrac {M-3m}{M+m}v\,\hat i$ and the other object has a velocity $\dfrac {3M-m}{M+m}v\,\hat i$.
Not unexpectedly if $M\gg m$ the velocity of the more massive object after the collision is approximately the same as its velocity before the collision $v \,\hat i$.
However the velocity of the less massive object is approximately $3v\,\hat i$ ie its velocity has reversed direction and is now three times the magnitude it had been before the collision the extra kinetic energy that is has coming from the kinetic energy of the more massive body.

This is equivalent to a [gravitational slingshot/assist](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath114/kmath114.htm) but via a different force of interaction.

Comment: There is no loss of kinetic energy after collision.

Answer (score 2):

Let us fix the frame of reference on the infinitely heavy body. Now the infinitely heavy body is stationary. The smaller body is travelling with a velocity 2v. And hence after an elastic collision with the infinitely heavy body should rebound with a velocity -2v.

Comment: +1 for the frame of reference, but it's worth noting the 2v velocity is ignoring the influence of gravity. The gravity of the ultra-massive body will of course accelerate the smaller body. The question also ignores that there's a relatively low limit to the mass of a single body (excluding black holes) - the [most massive star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R136a1) is about 315 solar masses or $6 \times 10^{32}$kg, which is a tad short of "very huge mass tending towards infinity".

Comment: @chappo The only way the question can be interpreted is to take it as an imaginary extension of the normal collisions. If a ball hits the wall it rebounds with no loss in velocity if the collision is elastic. Then one asks what if the wall were also moving towards the ball. If you bring complications you simply have no solution.

Comment: So what’s the purpose of the additional expression “tending to infinity”? I recognise it might just be a poorly worded question. But if we’re not meant to ignore the expression, we should consider its implications.